# Go json Marshaller panics with "call of reflect.Value.Int on zero Value"

Tags: go, marshalling, panic

I am trying to unmarshal some data in a complex struct with multi-level nesting (thus, not copying the struct here). However, when the code went live, we started getting the following panic in rare occasions (difficult to quantify but perhaps 1 in 1000 cases).

Below is the stack trace of the issue:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Int on zero Value [recovered]
        panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Int on zero Value

    goroutine 568428 [running]:
    encoding/json.(*encodeState).marshal.func1(0xc0081d5c70)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:305 +0x9a
    panic(0x13968c0, 0xc005c2f540)
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
    reflect.Value.Int(...)
            /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:986
    encoding/json.intEncoder(0xc0074b5dc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0038b0100)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:522 +0x1d4
    encoding/json.mapEncoder.encode(0x1608760, 0xc0074b5dc0, 0x1385c20, 0xc00119f5e0, 0x195, 0x100)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:706 +0x351
    encoding/json.structEncoder.encode(0xc0002ce600, 0x19, 0x21, 0xc00027ede0, 0xc0074b5dc0, 0x156c820, 0xc00119f510, 0x199, 0x520100)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:664 +0x306
    encoding/json.ptrEncoder.encode(0xc00027ee10, 0xc0074b5dc0, 0x1397e80, 0xc00119f510, 0x16, 0x1390100)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:810 +0xb1
    encoding/json.(*encodeState).reflectValue(0xc0074b5dc0, 0x1397e80, 0xc00119f510, 0x16, 0x100)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:337 +0x82
    encoding/json.(*encodeState).marshal(0xc0074b5dc0, 0x1397e80, 0xc00119f510, 0xc003da0100, 0x0, 0x0)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:309 +0x10b
    encoding/json.Marshal(0x1397e80, 0xc00119f510, 0x40be53, 0x13c4160, 0x1397e80, 0x1, 0x7fa9d5d348b0)
            /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/encode.go:161 +0x52
    reingames.com/rm/user.(*userCore).MarshalBinary(0xc00119f510, 0x1397e80, 0xc00119f510, 0x7fa9d5d348b0, 0xc00119f510, 0x1)
            /home/shivam/goprojects/rmgs/go/user/profile.go:180 +0x37
```

I have no clue where to start debugging this. Has anyone experienced something similar? Quick question - could a race condition (marshalling a pointer while it is being updated) cause this panic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to start debugging is : catch the panic with a `recover()` instruction, and log information about the context of the error.

This wouldn't catch a race condition "in the act", but it would certainly help you understand more things about your error (does it occur always on the same elements ? is the element still in a valid state ? etc ...)

Comment: While @hobbs suggestion was great, I could not implement it on the live server - considering the warning on the degraded performance / memory. Instead, I chose to go with this suggestion and set up an email alert in the defer - recover() construct to catch the issues. It was race condition indeed. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a race could cause almost anything, including this. If you have any tests to speak of, run them with
`go test -race`. If not, or if that doesn't turn anything up, you might consider canarying a build with
`go build -race`, but see [the race detector documentation](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector) for caveats about performance and memory usage in that case. You may just want to inspect the code yourself for races.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, we also have this problem, you can check whether it is a coroutine in the code,Is there a right slice operate。Slice relies on array implementation. When the underlying array has sufficient capacity, the append operation is not a read-only operation, and elements are directly added to the free position of the array. Therefore, when a multi-coroutine performs an append operation on a global slice, it will operate on the same underlying data, causing read-write conflicts. Causes the exception of Go json Marshaller.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30495582)